# MS Access get row ID of Update or intercept Update

Tags: vba, ms-access, crud, oltp

Short Version:

> I have an access table that has a Yes/No column called `[Accepted]`
>   that I want flipped to "No" anytime an update happens to that row.  How can
>   I do this?  I've been working with `Form_AfterUpdate` in VBA but no luck
>   so far.

Long Version:

> I'm trying to get CRUD working with my OLTP back-end SQL SERVER using
>   Access.  I'm exploring the possibility of using Access as a
>   simple front end for office work but want it to jive with our larger data operation. I've designed a *Main Form* with
>   `Edit`, `Cancel`, `Save`, and `Refresh` buttons.  In the body of that
>   form I've embedded a *Sub-form* containing a **datasheet**.  My `Edit`
>   button unlocks the sheet in the *Sub-form* for insert and delete.  This
>   *Sub-form* is bound to a local access table which serves as a cash. 
>   The `Refresh` button rebases my Access table/cache with the OLTP server and
>   the `Save` button writes any records in my Access table/cache marked
>   as `[Accepted]=No` to the OLTP server and then refreshes.

Any suggestions on how I could better get CRUD working with OLTP and Access are appreciated as that is the full goal here.  However, I think I'm close on my own if I can figure out how to intercept or get the record ID of updated rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the *Form_BeforeUpdate* event:

```
Me!Accepted.Value = False
```